# Finding employee that made the most from array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have managed to get the "least" Calculated however the code for "most" is not working... what I have currently.

```
for (int i = 0; i < workerGrossIncome.Length; i++)                   

         if (workerGrossIncome[i] > workerGrossIncome[maxIndex])
            {
                maxIndex = i;
                workerMost = workerName[i];
                workerRegularPayMost = workersRegularPay[i];
                workerGrossIncomeMost = workerGrossIncome[i];
            }
```

edit with full code: (Currently Learning cannot use built in array methods)
Program runs however uses the defaults when calculating for the worker that made the most during the work week.

```
    const double FEDERAL_TAX_DEDUCTION = .10; //10% of Gross Income
    const double STATE_TAX_DEDUCTION = .05;   //5% of Gross Income
    const double workerOvertimePay = 0.00;    //If Employee Does No Overtime

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int MAX_LIST_VALUE;

        Write("How Many Worker's Are Working? ");
        MAX_LIST_VALUE = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());

        string[] workerName = new string[MAX_LIST_VALUE]; 
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LIST_VALUE; i++)
        {
              WriteLine("Please Enter The Worker's Name: ");
              workerName[i] = ReadLine();  
        }
        double[] workerWages = new double[MAX_LIST_VALUE];
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LIST_VALUE; i++)
        {
              WriteLine("Please Enter The Worker's Hourly Wage: ");
              workerWages[i] = Convert.ToDouble(ReadLine());
        }
        double[] workerWeeklyHours = new double[MAX_LIST_VALUE];
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LIST_VALUE; i++)
        {
            Write("How many hours has {0} worked this week? ", workerName[i]);
            workerWeeklyHours[i] = Convert.ToDouble(ReadLine());                
        }

        double[] workersRegularPay = new double[MAX_LIST_VALUE];
        double[] workerGrossIncome = new double[MAX_LIST_VALUE];
        double[] workerStateTaxAmount = new double[MAX_LIST_VALUE];
        double[] workerFederalTaxAmount = new double[MAX_LIST_VALUE];
        double[] workerNetIncome = new double[MAX_LIST_VALUE];
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LIST_VALUE; i++)
        {
            workersRegularPay[i] = workerWeeklyHours[i] * workerWages[i];
            workerGrossIncome[i] = workerWeeklyHours[i] * workerWages[i];
            workerStateTaxAmount[i] = workerGrossIncome[i] * STATE_TAX_DEDUCTION;
            workerFederalTaxAmount[i] = workerGrossIncome[i] * FEDERAL_TAX_DEDUCTION;
            workerNetIncome[i] = workerGrossIncome[i] - workerFederalTaxAmount[i] - workerStateTaxAmount[i];
        }

        WriteLine("There Are " + MAX_LIST_VALUE + " Workers!");
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LIST_VALUE; i++)
        {                
            WriteLine("Worker's Name: " + workerName[i]);
            WriteLine(workerName[i] + " Hourly Wage: " + workerWages[i].ToString("C"));
            WriteLine(workerName[i] + " Hours Wokred This Week: " + workerWeeklyHours[i]);
            WriteLine(workerName[i] + " Regular Pay: " + workersRegularPay[i].ToString("C"));
            WriteLine(workerName[i] + " Gross Income Pay: " + workerGrossIncome[i].ToString("C"));
            WriteLine(workerName[i] + " State Tax Amount: " + workerStateTaxAmount[i].ToString("C"));
            WriteLine(workerName[i] + " Federal Tax Amount: " + workerFederalTaxAmount[i].ToString("C"));
            WriteLine(workerName[i] + " Net Income: " + workerNetIncome[i].ToString("C"));
        }
        ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        WriteLine("\nPress Enter To Continue For Worker's That Earned The Least & Most.");
        ReadLine();

        int minIndex = 0;
        string workerLeast = "null";
        double workerRegularPayLeast = 0,
               workerGrossIncomeLeast = 0,
               workerOverTimeLeast = 0;
        int maxIndex = 0;
        string workerMost = "null";
        double workerRegularPayMost = 0,
               workerGrossIncomeMost = 0,
               workerOverTimeMost = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < workerGrossIncome.Length; i++)
            if (workerGrossIncome[i] < workerGrossIncome[minIndex])
            {
                minIndex = i;
                workerLeast = workerName[i];
                workerRegularPayLeast = workersRegularPay[i];
                workerGrossIncomeLeast = workerGrossIncome[i];                    
            }
        for (int i = 0; i < workerGrossIncome.Length; i++)
            if (workerGrossIncome[i] > workerGrossIncome[maxIndex])   //Doesnt calc the most..... FIX
            {
                maxIndex = i;
                workerMost = workerName[i];
                workerRegularPayMost = workersRegularPay[i];
                workerGrossIncomeMost = workerGrossIncome[i];
            }
        ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        WriteLine("\nThe Worker That Earned The Least Is {0}!", workerLeast);
        WriteLine("{0}'s Gross Income Was {1}.", workerLeast, workerGrossIncomeLeast.ToString("C"));
        WriteLine("{0}'s Regular Pay Was {1}.", workerLeast, workerRegularPayLeast.ToString("C"));
        WriteLine("{0}'s Overtime Pay Was {1}.", workerLeast, workerOverTimeLeast.ToString("C"));
        ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
        WriteLine("\nThe Worker That Earned The Most Is {0}!", workerMost);
        WriteLine("{0}'s Gross Income Was {1}.", workerMost, workerGrossIncomeMost.ToString("C"));
        WriteLine("{0}'s Regular Pay Was {1}.", workerMost, workerRegularPayMost.ToString("C"));
        WriteLine("{0}'s Overtime Pay Was {1}.", workerMost, workerOverTimeMost.ToString("C"));
        ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Error is in the loop for worker earning the most. The rest is fine for whats needed.

Comment: Not enough info here. Only thing I can see is the first go through the loop it compares index 0 with itself...but I doubt that's your problem.

Comment: If the highest paid person is at index 0 you'll never set your variables like you want to because WorkerStats come[0] can never be great than itself because they are equal

Comment: why not sort the list and take the top(highest paid) or bottom(least paid)?

Comment: I however agree with @BenHall we need more info

Comment: why don;t you show the code for the least amount that you claim is working also .. look at your code if it works for the least amount.. then copy that code and change the values / variables / condition, to work for the max are we to guess what you have done in the working code..? also perhaps your conditional check should be the following instead `if (workerGrossIncome[i] >=`

Comment: I think it is a rather bad modeling of creating three independent arrays. Usually in that case on creates an object or struct of an `Employee`.

Comment: I totally agree with @WillemVanOnsem.
Then you can use Linq. employees.Max(employe => employee.Income)

Comment: @FerdinandBrunauer I suspect you would want `MaxBy` since the OP is interested in more properties than **just** the income.

Comment: Did either answer work for you @ElliotO ?

Answer (score 0):

#### Without LINQ

If you can't use LINQ, then change your `maxIndex` variable declaration to:

```
int? maxIndex = null;
```

And the start of your loop to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < workerGrossIncome.Length; i++)
    if (maxIndex == null || workerGrossIncome[i] > workerGrossIncome[maxIndex.Value])
```

to ensure that the code work even when **the first element is the largest one**.

*Your existing code does not work if the first element is the largest since `workerGrossIncome[i] > workerGrossIncome[maxIndex]` will be `false` and thus `workerMost` etc won't be set.*

#### With LINQ

If you add the [MoreLINQ Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) then `maxIndex` can be calculated as follows:

```
// Sample Data
int[] workerGrossIncome = new[] {1, 2, 4};

var maxIndex = workerGrossIncome
    .Select((value, index) => new {index, value})
    .MaxBy(z => z.value)
    .index;

var workerMost = workerName[i];
var workerRegularPayMost = workersRegularPay[i];
var workerGrossIncomeMost = workerGrossIncome[i];
```

`Select` will project the original data **and** the index. `MaxBy` will find the item with the largest `value`. `index` will return the index of that matching item.